# Installation Package, for using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I have pretty low experience with Python, but I'm tasked with creating an installation package so that I can distribute a GUI that messes with Time Series of Stocks taken from online. Based on what I've seen online, Python 3.4.1 has a built in module called ensurepip and pip, but for some reason I try and execute " python -m ensurepip" on the Python Shell, I get "Invalid Syntax"

I'm hoping to use pip to install all the dependencies for Pandas myself, but this is just one problem of many I suppose.

Edit: Slight update I suppose. I've checked my files and I know ensurepip is in the library of modules, and I've tried going through https://docs.python.org/3.4/installing/index.html and can't make heads or tails of it from my issues. Thanks in advance.

Edit2:http://puu.sh/azkqQ/4a5606a1f5.jpg 
Picture indicating what I get. I've tried on the Command Prompt without the py and within the py

Answer (score 0):

you're calling that command from the *python* shell. but it should be called from the command line. so just open up `cmd` or `terminal` and run that there, you should be fine.

and in the future, you should show the entire error. you probably got something like:

```
python -m ensurepip
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I attempted to run this from Command Prompt as well. It didn't work, assuming that's what you mean by the Command Line.

Comment: yeah, you need to make sure python's on your path. just a hint for the general way to debug things, you have to read the error so you know what you're dealing with. "it didn't work" won't help you solve anything.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure where to read this error, I've stated everything that I've seen. How do I ensure Python is on my path for the files?